# Replace string.empty and Show "Null" using linq to xml?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I need to show null or zero, instead of showing string empty.

Xml Response:

```
<Items>
   <Item>
     <ASIN>111</ASIN>
      <ItemAttributes>
       <Title>xxx</Title>
      <ListPrice>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
         <FormattedPrice>45.25</FormattedPrice>
        </ListPrice>
        </ItemAttributes>
        <Variation>
        <Item>
         <ItemAttributes>
            <Title>yes</Title>
          </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
        </Variation>
     </Item>
   <Item>
     <ASIN>222</ASIN>
      <ItemAttributes>
       <Title>yyy</Title>
       </ItemAttributes>
         <Variation>
        <Item>
         <ItemAttributes>
            <Title>No</Title>
          </ItemAttributes>
        </Item>
        </Variation>
    </Item>
   <Items>
```

Here is my code.,

```
var Price1 = xd.Descendants(ns + "ListPrice").Select(c => new
{
    PPrice = (c.Element(ns + "FormattedPrice") != null) ? 
             c.Element(ns + "FormattedPrice").Value : **string.Empty**
}).ToList();
```

How to replace String.Empty with Value like "Null" or 0. Thanks in advance.
 From Xml response if the "FormattedPrice" is not available for Item Two, It Should 
 show or null in the list.

Comment: which case is null and which case is 0?

Comment: @CuongLe If the condition is failed, here it shows string.empty. Instead of that i have to show any text it may be "Null" or number '0'.

Comment: but showing error"no implicit conversion b/w string and int.

Comment: That's weird, try to put again `"0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using an anonymous type at all here, and if you use the explicit `string` conversion you can avoid the conditional operator too. Of course you could easily have changed `string.Empty` to `"null"` and that *really* should work fine - if it's not, then there's something else wrong.

Anyway, here's the simplified code using "Null" instead (and a more conventional variable name):

```
var prices = xd.Descendants(ns + "ListPrice")
               .Select(c => ((string) c.Element(ns + "Price")) ?? "0")
               .ToList();
```

It's possible you don't need the brackets around `(string) c.Element(ns + "FormattedPrice")` - I can't remember offhand what has higher precedence out of the cast or the null coalescing operator.

EDIT: To handle the situation where there's no `ListPrice` element, if you're already at the level of a *single item* you can just use:

```
var price = (string) item.Element(ns + "ListPrice").Element(ns + "Price") ?? "0";
```

Getting a list of prices and somehow inferring where to insert a "0" when `ListPrice` is absent would require you to find `Items` instead, e.g.

```
var prices = xd.Descendants(ns + "Item")
               .Select(item => item.Elements("ListPrice")
                                   .Select(c => (string) c.Element(ns + "Price"))
                                   .FirstOrDefalut() ?? "0")
               .ToList();
```

This would *only* be the prices though, not the other item data, which would be pretty odd.

Comment: @Thirisangu: Other than changing `FormattedPrice` for `Price`, and `"Null"` for `"0"`, it's not clear what you think wouldn't work from my answer.

Comment: @Thirisangu: Your XML doesn't contain FormattedPrice *anywhere*, and you wrote: "from Xml response if the "Price" is not available for Item Two". It's impossible to give you a good answer if you keep being inconsistent. You never mentioned what you wanted to happen if `ListPrice` wasn't available at all. Note that my code won't return null - it will return an empty list, which isn't the same thing. Also, if `ListPrice` isn't available, that's a pretty different situation to the one that most of the question talks about.

Comment: That mistakes was mine. I didn't give enough information to you. But your code is correct. Now i have changed. Thanks

Comment: @Thirisangu: I've added some more options in an edit, but please be careful to ask questions with correct and consistent information in the future. Read my guide to asking good questions at http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: ., It shows in second line as,"Does not contain a definition for 'select' and no extension method 'select' accepting a first argument type linq.xelement could not be found.

Comment: Please take a look at second select statement. It shows above error: var prices = xd.Descendants(ns + "Item")
               .Select(item => item.Element("ListPrice")
                                   .Select(c => (string)c.Element(ns + "Price"))
                                   .FirstOrDefalut() ?? "0")
               .ToList();

Comment: Please look at the XML Response, I have edited, I should have included before. Sorry., Thank you so much for your supporting.

Comment: @Thirisangu: It would have helped if you'd said which snippet. I'd fixed the second snippet... Fixing the other one now, although it's important that you *understand* the code, in which case you could probably have fixed it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for the above question.

```
var Title = xd.Descendants(ns + "Items").Elements(ns + "Item").Select(DVDTitle =>DVDTitle.Elements(ns + "ItemAttributes").Select(DVDTitle1 => (string)DVDTitle1.Element(ns + "Title")).FirstOrDefault() ?? "Null").ToList();
```